# Capping timeout change

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function checkBanner() {
    show = false;
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("zy181gg$xxxxx") < 0 ) { 
        show = true;
        click_on(); 
        var expDate = new Date();
        expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime()+5*60*1000);
        document.cookie = "gyz$xxx=zy181gg$xxxxx; expires=" + expDate.toGMTString() + "path=/";
    }
}
```

What set on `+5*60*1000` to display once on 24h ?

Comment: Sorry I can't see a question here. Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean it's expiring in 5 minutes, and you want to change to 24 hours:

```
expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
```

That's 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour, 60 seconds in a minute, and 1000 milliseconds in a second.